# Azure functions throwing error when trying to debug on MacOS

Tags: macos, azure, azure-functions

Trying to debug an Azure functions project.
On the mac clicking F5 and starting the debug.

And the output is this :

```
[2021-07-25T08:47:57.429Z] Cannot create directory for shared memory usage: /dev/shm/AzureFunctions
[2021-07-25T08:47:57.434Z] System.IO.FileSystem: Access to the path '/dev/shm/AzureFunctions' is denied. Operation not permitted.
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')
```

Has anybody encountered this before and know how to fix this ?
I tried running visual studio code with administrator permissions like this :
sudo open ./Visual\ Studio\ Code.app

Also tried to mkdir the /dev/shm directory but it just keeps giving this error.
What should I do ?

Comment: The first and second log that you see is a warning, check [this line](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/blob/dev/azure_functions_worker/bindings/shared_memory_data_transfer/file_accessor_unix.py#L131)
You can refer to [Azure Functions Core Tools error (OSX) : /dev/shm/AzureFunctions - shared memory usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/396617/azure-functions-core-tools-error-osx-devshmazurefu.html)

Comment: you can also refer to [Azure Functions local debugging broke with 3.17.0 update](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/azure-functions-local-debugging-broke-with-3170-up/1304718?viewtype=solution)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution was adding --verbose mode and see the logs. The problem was that azure didn't support node version 15. Downgraded nodejs to version 13.12.0 and it worked.

Comment: how do you start the debug session in verbose mode?

Comment: @D.Reagan https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/config

Comment: https://nodejs.org/download/release/v14.19.0/

Comment: Open terminal, change to api folder, and enter 
func start --verbose

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Downgrade nodejs to 14.x
https://nodejs.org/download/release/v14.19.0/

Step 2: run in verbose mode
Open terminal, change to api folder, and enter the below command
`func start --verbose`